# Linq query List<List<class>> Where property of class C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

Could someone suggest a way for me to select one of the lists within a parent list where one of it's elements has a certain property value?

```
public class HierarchyLevel
{
    public string Abbreviation;
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public Type LevelType;
    public List<HierarchyLevel> Children = new List<HierarchyLevel>();
}


public static List<List<HierarchyLevel>> ElementaryTypes = new List<List<HierarchyLevel>>();
```

I am actually trying to get the List that has the LevelType field of a specific type.

Comment: what are you specifically searching for in `LevelType` can you explain

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stackoverflow is not a code generating tool. In order to receive help, show us that you have atleast tried something

Comment: When you want a list of a given type for easy access maybe a Dictionary<Type, List<HierarchyLevel>> would suit your needs?

Comment: @Pieterkii are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: @user743414 That sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user743414 for pointing out how simple this was :)
By using a dictionary instead, I could reference to the specific list. (This is also a faster option.)

```
Dictionary<Type,List<HierarchyLevel>> HierarchicalData;
```

I can now use it with a key of 'Type':

```
private void UpdateGeneralData(object Entity, Dictionary<Type,List<HierarchyLevel>> TypeData)
{
    CBType.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in TypeData[Entity.GetType()])
    {
        CBType.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I am actually trying to get the List that has the LevelType field of a specific type.

What do you want if you've got several `HierarchyLevels` with this `LevelType`? And what do you want if there are no `HierarchyLevels` at all with this `LevelType`?

Let's assume that you want all HierarchyLevels with this `LevelType`. If later on you only want the first, or the one with a certain Abbreviation (or whatever), you could always use `.FirstOrDefault`, or `.Where`. and do a `ToList` in the end.

Implementing it as an extension function. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<HierarchyLevel> GetHierarchyLevelsWithLevelType(
    this IEnumerable<HierarchyLevel> hierarchyLevels,
    LevelType desiredLevelType)
{
    foreach (var hierarchyLevel in hierarchyLevels)
    {
        if (hierarchyLevel.LevelType == desiredLevelType)
        {    // found one!
             yield return hierarchyLevel;
        }

        // using recursion: check all the Children
        IEnumerable<HierarchyLevel> childrenWithDesiredLevelType = hierarchyLevel.Children
            .GetHierarchyLevelsWithLevelType(desiredLevelType);
        foreach(var childWithDesiredLevelType in childrenWithDesiredLevelType)
        {
            yield return childWithDesiredLevelType;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the recursion all Grandchildren and their Children etc will be returned

usage:

```
var allSpecialHierarchies = myHierarchies.GetHierarchyLevelsWithLevelType(LevelType.Special);

// get the first:
var firstSpecialHierarchy = allSpecialHierarchies.FirstOrDefault();
// get the first three named "Shakespeare:
var threeShakesPeares = allSpecialHierarchies
    .Where(hierarchyLevel => hierarchyLevel.Name == "Shakespeare")
    .Take(3)
```

For better usage you should provide a version that has a parameter `IQualityComparer<LevelType>`. Let the function above call that one.

And a nice challenge: to be fully LINQ compatible, create a version with a predicate that returns a type T and an equality comparer for this type T, so that you can have all HierarchyLevels with a certain Name, or Abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can Solve your with the help of `recursion` consider example below :- I have taken sample type of `String` you can use any of your `Type`

```
List<List<HierarchyLevel>> sample = new List<List<HierarchyLevel>>();

Type yourType = typeOf(string);

List<HierarchyLevel> filtered = sample.Where(x => ContainsElement(x, yourType));

public void bool ContainsElement(List<HierarchyLevel> list,Type yourType)
{
  if(list.Any(x => x.LevelType == yourType)      //check if current node has same level type
     return true;
  else if(list.Childern.Count > 0)              //check if current node has children if yes then call ContainsElement again
     return list.Children.Any(x => ContainsElement(x,yourType));
  else
     return false;                              //else return false in last
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (?):

```
   List<HierarchyLevel> var = hLevel.Select(h => h.Children.Where(c => c.Param = "desired param")).ToList();
```